# CORS error when calling post api directly from client

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have a post function that I have tested and is working perfectly. When I call it from my front end, I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sdigg5u4xb.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/sites' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried disabling CORS and using different cognito identity pools to allow different permissions, but I still get the same error. When testing it in AWS, it is successful with no errors.

Here is where I am calling the API:

```
import { API } from "aws-amplify";

export default (async function submitSite(values) {
  console.log(values);
  return API.post("sites", "/sites", {
    body: values
  }) 
});
```

Here is where I am defining the function in my serverless.yml file:

```
createSite:
    handler: CreateSite.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: sites
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to check these.

- Make sure you enable CORS in your API gateway as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)
- Make sure your server less app have CORS enabled [here](https://serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/).
- Don't forget adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to your function.

  ```
  module.exports.hello = function(event, context, callback) {

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ "message": "Hello World!" })
  };

  callback(null, response);
  ```

Comment: I appreciate the response, yes my CORS is enabled and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is added